# Lables reading a text box

Tags: c#, forms

Can I use a label from one form to read from data entered into a textbox on another form? An example is entering a number in a text box and having that information displayed with the label on the other form

Comment: When you have a question like this ask yourself the opposite - "is there a chance it's impossible to pass data from one form to the next?". If it's impossible - wouldn't you have made a major break-through in computing :D.  A better question would be "how do I..." and google it first

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's not too rough. The general concept is that the source form (where the textbox resides) supplies the necessary value to the destination form (where the label resides). Here is a small example:

SourceForm:

```
namespace DataTransferBetweenForms
{
    public partial class SourceForm : Form
    {
        public SourceForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var destinationForm = new DestinationForm();
            destinationForm.LabelText = textBox1.Text;
            destinationForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

DestinationForm:

```
namespace DataTransferBetweenForms
{
    public partial class DestinationForm : Form
    {
        public string LabelText
        {
            get { return label1.Text; }
            set { label1.Text = value; }
        }

        public DestinationForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Now when the SourceForm's button1_Click event is triggered, an instance of DestinationForm is created, the label's Text property is set, and the DestinationForm instance is shown.